# Sphinx docs including unit test output

Tags: python-sphinx

This is a how-to/best-practice question.

- I have a code base with a suite of unit tests run with `pytest`
- I have a set of `*.rst` files which provide explanation of each test, along with a table of results and images of some mathematical plots
- Each time the pytest suite runs, it dynamically updates the `*.rst` files with the results of the latest test data, updating numerical values, time-stamping the tests, etc

I would like to integrate this with the project docs. I could

- Build these rst files separately with `sphinx-build` whenever I want to view the test results [this seems bad, since it's labor intensive and not automated]
- tell Sphinx to render these pages separately and include them in the project docs [better, but I'm not sure how to configure this]
- have a separate set of sphinx docs for the test results which I can build after each run of the test suite

Which approach (or another approach) is most effective? Is there a best practice for doing this type of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look into [Sphinx-Test-Reports](https://sphinx-test-reports.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which reads in all information from junit-based xml-files (pytest supports this) and generates the output during the normal sphinx build phase.

So you are free to add custom information around the test results.

[Example from webpage:](http://localhost:63342/sphinx-test-reports/docs/_build/html/directives/test_report.html#example)

```
.. test-report:: My Report
   :id: REPORT
   :file: ../tests/data/pytest_sphinx_data_short.xml
```

So complete answer to your question: Take none of the given approaches and let a sphinx-extension do it during build-time.